# Why did word final S get replaced by "CE" in Middle and Modern English?

Tags: etymology, orthography

There are many words in English that have **ce** at the end in Modern English. The roots they have come from had **s** but replaced by **ce** in Modern English. Is there any reason why the **s**'s got replaced by **ce**? Why did this happen?

Look at the following examples to see what I mean:

"[race](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/race)":

> From Middle English *race*, from Old Norse ***rás***

"[ice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ice)":

> From Middle English ***is***, from Old English ***īs***

"[rice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rice)":

> From Middle English ***rys***, from Old French ***ris***, from Old Italian *riso*, *risi*

"[peace](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peace)":

> From Middle English ***pes***, ***pais***, ***pees***, borrowed from Anglo-Norman ***peis*** and Old French ***pais***

"[ace](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ace)":

> From Middle English ***as***, from Old French ***as***, from Latin ***as***, *assis*

"[pace](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pace)":

> Borrowed into Middle English from Anglo-Norman ***pas***, Old French ***pas***, and their source, Latin *passus*. Doublet of *pas*; cf. also *pass*. Cognate with Spanish *pasear*

"[juice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/juice)":

> From Middle English ***jus***, ***juis***, from Old French ***jus***, ***jous***, from Latin ***jūs***

Comment: Most of the other entries are convincing but there is a  very short temporal overlap between the beginning of rice cultivation in Italy (mid to late 15c according to [this website](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3827184/)) and the end of the Middle English linguistic period (around 1500). The word 'rys' must have been adopted quickly and with very little experience of the grain for it to have entered Middle English.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: the *s* was replaced by *-ce* to avoid confusion the /z/ sound represented by the letter *s* in Old English.

That change seems to be sporadic. As you can see, the majority of the words in the OP are of French/Norman origin. You may have noticed that the letter ᴄ in Modern English is usually pronounced /s/ before ɪ, ʏ and ᴇ; it was a spelling convention introduced by French scribes.

According [*The History of English Spelling by Chrisopher Upward*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_English_Spelling.html?id=fNfebt79zdwC), by the time of the Norman Invasion, French *c* was pronounced /s/ before ɪ, ʏ, ᴇ in words of both French origin and Old English (OE), for example:

- Middle English (ME) *cite* < Old French *cité*
- Middle English *mice* < OE *mȳs*

Upward says that word-final s was often replaced by -ᴄᴇ in ME and Early ModE period as in: *ace* < French *as*, *juice* < *jus*, *palace* < *palais*, though he doesn't explain *why*.

For the *why*, I consulted [*A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles: Volume 1, Sounds and Spellings by Otto Jespersen*](https://books.google.com/books?id=80wAE6kSOB4C). According to Jespersen, Old French ᴄ was originally pronounced /ts/ but then it simplified to /s/. What he says about OE *se* suggests that it had the value /z/ in OE. He says:

> **But to avoid mistakes with *-se* = /z/ English has introduced *-ce* into a great many words which in ME were spelt with *-s*** [...] [emphasis mine]
>
> The spelling *-ce* was even applied to native words in order to denote the voiceless sound unambiguously after final *-s* had become voiced [...]

(pp 49-50)

The last two lines account for the words of OE origin that are spelt with -ᴄᴇ: *īs* ‘ice’, *mȳs* ‘mice’, *lȳs* ‘lice’, *flēos* ‘fleece’